# Is spitters' attack range equal to turret range?

Tags: factorio

I was considering building a defense that will prevent spitters from attacking turrets immediately by forcing them to walk around walls first. But is their range smaller than that of the turrets? Is larger spitters' attack range greater?

Comment: This may help: https://www.reddit.com/r/factorio/comments/4cweob/spitter_range/.  I've never tried the belt technique, but I think I will in the future...

Comment: @TimmyJim Wow, that's cool. Gotta try that when I get home!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [version history](https://wiki.factorio.com/Version_history/0.11.0#0.11.6) as for version 0.11.6 the range of all spitters have been set to 15, so they don't outrange the turrets, and this didn't change since then as I know.

As Timmy Jim mentioned, common tactics againts spitters is placing belts in front of walls to push them outrange. As the spitters step on the belts, they begin to move, and when they try to spit, the belt pushes them out of range, forcing them to move again before they can get their acid off.

Example of pushing biters back off walls:

[image]
In the same manner you can build longer belts to keep spitters at distance.

Some players consider reverse tactics: pushing off the biters, but pulling in the spitters, as shows here:

[image]

Obviously, faster belts are better.

Comment: Why pull in the spitters?

Comment: @TomášZato in older versions spitters were able to outrange gun turrets, so you need to pull them closer. Another point - if you have two rows of turrets then farther turrets cannot reach spitters.

Answer (score 1):

According to the wiki, spitters have a range of 15, gun turrets have a range of 17, laser turrets have a range of 25, and flame turrets have a range of 30 but are limited to a 45 degree firing arc.

So using the belt trick already outlined in Exerion's answer, any turret not only has a higher range than spitters, but will never even be attacked by them due to the belts interrupting their attack.